# Which mysql server package should I install?

Tags: mysql

I just switched hosts and now have the task of reinstalling everything. I'm on CentOS now and I need to install mysql but have no idea which package to install. I can't seem to find any info on the differences either. Would anyone know? Yum is not an option as it wants to install 1.0.77 and this is too old. The machine is 64 bit.

Comment: You said '1.0.77', but CentOS ships with MySQL 5.0.77. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

If the version you want to install differs from the version supported in your distribution and you have no reason to compile from source, I'd say your best off seeking MySQL's precompiled binaries.

A very rough procedure is listed below.  You might want to remove the `mysql` and `mysql-server` packages from your system, which means you would need to use a different init and create a mysql user.  You may have system packages dependent on it.

I tend to make my primary server roles (IE. Web, mail, proxy) built around scripts and source distribution as opposed to distribution packages, while using distribution packages for core system utilities and libraries.  This is simply my preference.

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://mysql.tar.gz
tar zxvf mysql.tar.gz -C /usr/local
ln -s /usr/local/mysql-$VERSION /usr/local/mysql
cd /usr/local/mysql
scripts/mysql_install_db --force  
chown -R root  .
chown -R mysql data
chgrp -R mysql .
/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
tail -f  /usr/local/mysql/data/`uname -n`.err
cd /usr/local/mysql/data
/bin/rm -fr test
```

[Download MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

Download the MySQL 5.1 RPMs from [dev.mysql.com](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads).

The RPMs are labeled "Red Hat & Oracle Enterprise Linux", but I believe they work fine for CentOS as well. I'm testing them on a CentOS 5.4 host now, and they installed without problems and seem to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

What version of CentOS did you install? On my recently-installed copy of CentOS 5.4, I show this:

```
[root@server ~]# yum info mysql-server
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: mirror.fdcservers.net
 * base: centos.mbni.med.umich.edu
 * epel: ftp.osuosl.org
 * extras: centos.omnispring.com
 * updates: mirror.ubiquityservers.com
Available Packages
Name       : mysql-server
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 5.0.77
Release    : 4.el5_4.2
Size       : 9.8 M
Repo       : updates
Summary    : The MySQL server and related files
URL        : http://www.mysql.com
License    : GPLv2 with exceptions
Description: MySQL is a multi-user, multi-threaded SQL database server. MySQL is a
           : client/server implementation consisting of a server daemon (mysqld)
           : and many different client programs and libraries. This package contains
           : the MySQL server and some accompanying files and directories.
```

Comment: Or did you just make a typo with "1.0.77"? I'm not sure if a more recent version is available from the official CentOS repositories. You always have the option to install the official binary or source packages to get up to the most recent revs, but that's just asking for headaches when you go to upgrade or do security patches in the future.